# R: Error in Reading a .DAT file directly from website

Tags: r, web, url, read.table

I'm trying to read a `.DAT` file directly from the [website](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring03/sta113/Data/Hand/Hand.html) and getting the following error:

```
abdomen <- read.table("https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring03/sta113/Data/Hand/abdomen.dat")

Error in file(file, "rt") : 
  cannot open the connection to 'https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring03/sta113/Data/Hand/abdomen.dat'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In eval(formal.args[[as.character(substitute(arg))]], envir = sys.frame(sysP)) :
  closing unused connection 4 (https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring03/sta113/Data/Hand/abdomen.dat)
2: In file(file, "rt") :
  URL 'https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring03/sta113/Data/Hand/abdomen.dat': status was 'Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates'
```

I also tried the following code:

```
abdomen <- read.table(url("https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring03/sta113/Data/Hand/abdomen.dat"))
Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : 
  cannot open the connection to 'https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring03/sta113/Data/Hand/abdomen.dat'
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(file, "rt") :
  URL 'https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring03/sta113/Data/Hand/abdomen.dat': status was 'Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates'
```

Any hint, please.

Comment: I'm getting no such error on either `read.table` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are blocked by your (corporate?) firewall. Make sure that your proxy settings work fine.

Stealing from my own answer on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55244646/error-in-usemethodhttp-error-in-roadoi/55607262#55607262):

```
## get the proxy settings
system("netsh winhttp show proxy")
Sys.setenv(HTTP_PROXY = <the proxy from netsh>, HTTPS_PROXY = <the proxy from netsh>)
```